# failing to start mysql server client after upgrading with brew (os Mojave)

Tags: mysql, macos

I just did `Brew update mysql` and then closed my mysql.

tried to start again and bam:

```
~ » mysql.server start                                                                                                                                                               
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Johns-MBP-2.pid).
```

never had this issue before, was going over all the stackoverflow answers about this situation and nothing worked :\

in the .err file I see:

`InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.`
`Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You possibly have another instance(s) of mysql running.

You can check with the command:

```
pgrep mysql
```

If it returns some id, you can kill it/them with the command below before attempting to start mysql again:

```
pkill mysql
```

---

**Update:**

If mysql keep spawning with a new process id, it probably means there's a mysql agent (daemon) that you need to unload first:

Check for it:

```
launchctl list | grep mysql
```

And acutally unload it:

```
launchctl unload "Library/LaunchAgents/$(launchctl list | grep mysql | grep -v grep | awk '{print $3}').plist"
```

Comment: its so weird, its like i have a permanent process running...i use ```pgrep mysql
``` and see process X, than I do ```pkill mysql``` and ```pgrep mysql
``` gives me another process...its like every time i do kill its just instantiating another one

Comment: if you keep getting a new process id after killing mysql, check your `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` folder, there must be a mysql daemon there (I updated my answer)